# Как реализовать авторизацию через Telegram на PHP?

Tags: php, telegram, auth

Мне нужно реализовать авторизацию пользователей через Telegram на моем сайте. В документации Telegram API не мог разобраться, в интернете одни мануалы по созданию ботов.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: У телеграма есть виджет авторизации. Читайте [документацию](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сайте уже есть авторизация? какова структура сайта?
Есл не ошибаюсь, официальной oauth2 авторизации через Телеграм нет.
Наиболее простой вариант - авторизировать через бота. Пользователь может начать чат с ботом по ссылке, передав дополнительные параметры. 
На стороне сайта вы просто можете сохранять в базу всех, кто постучит боту.
За счет параметров в ссылке можно точно определить что пользователь пришел с сайта и проверять актуальность ключа. 
В качестве логина можно использовать ID телеграма, высылать пароль при регистрации или восстановлении.

Этот называется **Deep linking** и описано в официальной [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking).

Вот минимальный пример кода из некогда рабочего бота.

```
<?php

// Telegram URL, token, API url
define('TOKEN', '***BOT_TOKEN***');
define('URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.TOKEN.'/');

// Bot input
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

// User data
$chat_id = $input['message']['chat']['id'];
$username = $input['message']['from']['username'];
$full_name = $input['message']['from']['last_name'].' '.$input['message']['from']['first_name'];
$date = $input['message']['date'];
$text = $input['message']['text'];

// User auth

if ( explode( ' ', $text )[1] == SITE_TOKEN ){

  $user = $DB->select( 'users', $chat_id );

  if ( !$user ){

    $userPassword = generatePassword();

    $DB->insert( 'users', makeUser( $chat, $userPassword, $full_name, $date ) );

    send_keyb(
      $chat,
      "Добро пожаловать, {$full_name}. Вы зарегистрированы как {$username}!
      Пароль для доступа к сайту: {$userPassword}",
      mainMenu()
    );
  }

  else {
    send_keyb(
      $chat,
      "Вы уже зарегистрированы как {$username}!
      Чтобы восстановить пароль, нажмите: /forot_password",
      mainMenu()
    );
  }
}
?>
```

Формат данных от пользователя при переходе по ссылке:

`https://telegram.me/your_site_bot?start=2a79RhELHUoC5stlOqI6pnz1bTmjuFMWSdye8xKZi4XcG0VNrJPBA3gfQDwkYv`

```
{"update_id":000000000,"message":{"message_id":0000,
"from":{"id":000000000,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"FIRST_NAME","username":"USERNAME","language_code":"en-US"},
"chat":{"id":000000000,"FIRST_NAME":"#","username":"USERNAME","type":"private"}, "date":1505645689,

/// USER TOKEN FROM SITE

"text":"/start 2a79RhELHUoC5stlOqI6pnz1bTmjuFMWSdye8xKZi4XcG0VNrJPBA3gfQDwkYv",

"entities":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"type":"bot_command"}]}}
```

так же есть реально рабочий пример на [github.com](https://github.com/TelegramPassport/passport-laravel)

Comment: как можно реализовать это с помощью get или post запросов как это делается например в vk api

Comment: Телеграм не поддерживает OAuth2 авторизацию, на сколько мне известно